# How to select particular rows on a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, limit

I have a table called 'topics' in which all topics are saved. I want to select the latest 5 rows from that table, show them on one page, then select THE OTHER FIVE latest ones and show them on the other page.

I know how to echo all the topic names in a while loop, but the problem here is making mysql select 5 rows, then the other five for another page, not the same ones again. How to achieve this?

Comment: That's what [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html#id973384) in combination with `ORDER BY` is for.

Comment: I'm using ORDER BY to show the latest ones (sorting by date). But the thing is that mysql_fetch_assoc moves the data pointer further, thus selecting each and every row on one page. I want to select 5 latest ones, use mysql_fetch_assoc to show them, then select another five and echo them on the other page

Comment: You could add some code probably to show what you're currently doing. E.g. the part where you build and fire the query and where you fetch the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
*
FROM tablename
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0, 5
```

on the another page:

```
LIMIT 5, 5
```

Comment: Thanks, great :) I have just did some research on the LIMIT tag in SQL. Didn't know it was actually that simple! I was afraid of having to re-write my whole code, but I knew there was just something that I was missing :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$start = 0;
$count= 5;
$query = "select *
    from topics
    order by date desc
    limit $start, $count"
```

Answer (score 0):

First 5:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY any_order_criteria LIMIT 0,5
```

Second 5:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY any_order_criteria LIMIT 5,5
```

Answer (score 0):

What i got from your problem is that you want to enable Pagination on your page.

This is a wonderful article on Pagination using PHP and MySQL.

http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/pagination.html

Comment: Yes, but I'm already near the result I want to achieve, so I don't want to follow those tutorials from scratch. This is only a tiny problem - moving the pointer by 5 rows (ahead).

Comment: Yes, I think @Ēriks Daliba has answered the question. I agree with him

Comment: I have just tested it out, the LIMIT works :) Thanks for the useful answer.

Comment: My pagination code is very simple, I want to keep it that way ;)